# Arduino: Why does while() loop with boolean argument cause dynamic memory to skyrocket?

Tags: c++, arduino, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am attempting to run communication between two RF transmitors on Arduino Uno boards.

---

When initiating the while() loop at the top of the code excerpt below, the dynamic memory usage shoots to 205% (4.2kB) if I use the '==' operator.

However, when using a single '=' as an assignment operator within the loop, this issue does not occur (obviously, the code does not function as required when this is the case).

This is where it gets interesting. Deleting the while() loop and its content completely does not reduce the dynamic memory usage. *So* it looks to me as if using an assignment operator within the loop actually reduces the dynamic memory usage of the entire sketch (to 15% / 325 bytes).

Oddly, it does not appear to be a leakage problem because even deleting the contents of the while() loop completely does not solve any problems.

I'm fairly fresh-faced to using C++ and Arduino, but assume it may be to do with assignment of global variables...

Any help troubleshooting why the dynamic memory usage is so high would be much appreciated!

---

I am coding in the Arduino IDE (v1.8.5), writing to an Arduino Uno (ATMega328 chip).

```
while (loop_var == true){
if (radio.sendWithRetry(TONODEID, &connection_checker, sizeof(connection_checker))){
  if (tick == 0) {
    Serial.print(F("Node ")); Serial.print(TONODEID); Serial.print(F(" detected. \n"));
    tick = 1;
  }
  loop_var = false;
} 
else {
  while (tock == 0){
    Serial.print(F("Node ")); Serial.print(TONODEID); 
    Serial.print(F(" - No ACK received, retrying... \n"));
    tock++;
  }
  loop_var = true;
}
```

Comment: You change will effect program flow only. Nothing directly to do with dynamic allocation.

Comment: Do you have more of your example?

Comment: @WilliamJBagshaw The sketch is fairly long, what other info would you require to clarify the question?

Comment: How much of the time do you expect "loop_var = true;" (as in the second loop) ?  If it is "most of the time" then memory usage might run high...  Do you have an output example?

Comment: Is tick and tock  changed by another thread or an interrupt? They will need to be volatile. The second lookp looks a bit strange. You only enter it if tock is zero and increment tock just before exit. So it could be an if()?

Comment: I think you are repeatedly calling radio.sendWithRetry() which is asynchronous so dynamically allocates its state and then returns.

Comment: @Drt the second loop runs most of the time, as I am using this to keep repeating the radio transmission in the first loop until it is successfully acknowledged by the receiver. As soon as this happens, the loop exits, allowing the programme to progress. How would you reduce memory usage from this second section?

Comment: @WilliamJBagshaw tick and tock will not be changed by any other threads / interrupts, so currently they are just defined as integers. Your point regarding the if() statement instead of a while() statement is a good one.

Comment: @WilliamJBagshaw I now avoid repeated calling of radio.sendWithRetry() by using a switch() case structure, but the problem persists.

Comment: Are you doing this outside of `setup` or `loop`?

Comment: @Matt this is part of a function which is called within `loop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about what's happening inside the loop, but what's happening outside.

The C++ compiler that comes bundled with Arduino is pretty smart. It figures out whether it is possible to reach an instruction or not. If a large declared variable is only referenced in a part of the code which will never be reached, it does not calculate the memory required for that variable while calculating dynamic memory.

A simple test case would be the following.

```
int test[100],test2[100];
void loop() {
  bool data=true;
#ifdef WHILE_COMPARE
  while(data == true ){
#else
  while(data = true){
#endif
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
      test[i]=0;
    }
    data=false;
  }
#ifdef USE_TEST2
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
      test2[i]=0;
    }
#endif
}
```

Now depending on which of the following combination are declared, the dynamic memory changes in the following manner.

WHILE_COMPARE is defined, USE_TEST2 is defined, the DM shoots to 402 bytes

WHILE_COMPARE is not defined, USE_TEST2 is defined, the DM is 209 bytes

WHILE_COMPARE is defined, USE_TEST2 is  not defined, the DM is 209 bytes

WHILE_COMPARE is not defined, USE_TEST2 is not defined, the DM is 209 bytes

I hope this helps.